# Verify email using NodeJS (Nodemailer) and Angular 2

Tags: node.js, email, angular

- Hi everyone, I would like to create a service in Angular 2 that when users input their email and click the submit button, it will send an active link to their email.
- I used Nodemailer in NodeJS to create API sending email. Now, how I can use Angular 2 to call this API. I read articles about this issue on forum however I could not solve this.

File EmailAPI.js:

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var router = express.Router();

let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    auth: {
        user: 'abc@gmail.com',
        pass: '111111'
    }
});

let mailOptions = {
    from: 'abc@gmail.com',
    to: 'xzy@gmail.com',
    subject: 'Test Mailer',
    text: 'I am testing Nodemailer to send email.',
};

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
    if (error) {
        return console.log(error);
    }
    console.log('Message %s sent: %s', info.messageId, info.response);
});
```

File Angular 2: email.services.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';


@Injectable()
export class EmailService {

  constructor(private http: Http ) { }

  public VerifyEmail() {

  }
}
```

Comment: Whats the problem? any error?

Comment: How I can use this API send email from angular 2, sir ?

Comment: @ryannguyen see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to construct a http call within your service which will point to your `Node` Application.

I recently wrote a `gist` for this on `GitHub` - [Angular 2 call Node Service](https://gist.github.com/Atkinson88/bb42d5c266816c48021df457e8b65091)

Excuse the formatting on the `Gist` It's on my radar to style it.

**Update**

First thing you need to do within your node project is set up a `route` I noticed you have declared `var router = express.Router();` but you're not actually using it.

So based off the `gist` I specified you could do something like this:

```
var express = require('express')

var app = express();

let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    auth: {
        user: 'abc@gmail.com',
        pass: '111111'
    }
});

let mailOptions = {
    from: 'abc@gmail.com',
    to: 'xzy@gmail.com',
    subject: 'Test Mailer',
    text: 'I am testing Nodemailer to send email.',
};

app.options('/sendmail', function (req, res) {
  res.sendStatus(200);
});


app.post('/sendmail', function (req, res) {

    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:4200'); // Change this to your Angular 2 port number
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Request-Method', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');

    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
        if (error) {
            return console.log(error);
        }
        console.log('Message %s sent: %s', info.messageId, info.response);
    });

})
```

I'm assuming your `node` project is a separate solution to your `Angular 2` project at this point. You'll then need to navigate to the root of your `node` project and run `node EmailAPI.js` this will run under a separate port to your `Angular 2` application. **NOTE** the port it's running under will be displayed after running `node EmailAPI.js`.

Now inside your `Angular 2` application you construct your `Http` call:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';


@Injectable()
export class EmailService {

  constructor(private http: Http ) { }

  public VerifyEmail() {
       return this.http.post(`http://localhost:3000/sendmail`, null, null).map(res => res.json());
  }
}
```

**NOTE** You'll see `http://localhost:3000` within the call, change this to the port name that is displayed after you have run `node EmailAPI.js`.

Additional information which I feel maybe well fitted to this, I highly recommend you look into [Postman - Testing your API's](https://www.getpostman.com/) this will help debug any errors you may experience - if any.

Comment: Thank you. Can you explain more clearly,  especially in this my above code.

Comment: @ryannguyen please see updated answer.

Comment: Very thank for your answer. How I can know my Angular 2 project connected to Node project ? Because I followed your answer but when I click button Send email on Angular 2, the console on Node project don't show successfull sending message.

Comment: Have you run the API call through postman? did you start up the node project? do you get any errors within the console?

Comment: Yes, I run request node on postman, it's run OK. Succesfully send email. However, when I click button on Angular project and monitor the console on Node project, it doesn't show anything.

Comment: Ok what about the developer console within your Angular 2 application.  when you call the node project do you see any errors?

Comment: Yes, it didn't show any errors. Do we have ways to know Angular 2 app can connected to server Node ?